# The PoiReadExcelFile class will read in the 'poi-test.xls' file into an HSSFWorkbook object

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've created this code and The PoiReadExcelFile class will read in the 'poi-test.xls' file into an HSSFWorkbook object. The 'POI Worksheet' will then be read into an HSSFWorksheet object, and then the values within the A1, B1, C1, and D1 cells will be read and displayed to standard output.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class PoiReadExcelFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("poi-    

      test.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("POI Worksheet");
        HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
        HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((short) 0);
        String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();
        HSSFCell cellB1 = row1.getCell((short) 1);
        String b1Val = cellB1.getStringCellValue();
        HSSFCell cellC1 = row1.getCell((short) 2);
        boolean c1Val = cellC1.getBooleanCellValue();
        HSSFCell cellD1 = row1.getCell((short) 3);
        Date d1Val = cellD1.getDateCellValue();

        System.out.println("A1: " + a1Val);
        System.out.println("B1: " + b1Val);
        System.out.println("C1: " + c1Val);
        System.out.println("D1: " + d1Val);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```

When i ran this code i got this:
Usage: BiffDrawingToXml [options] inputWorkbook
Options:
  -exclude-workbook            exclude workbook-level records
  -sheet-indexes      output sheets with specified indexes
  -sheet-namek          output sheets with specified name

What's the problem?

Comment: How exactly did you run your code?

Comment: i am using eclipse as editor!

Comment: You need to add program parameter in eclipse's run configratuion.

Comment: would you mind helping me how i do this?

Comment: `BiffDrawingToXml` is a class that is shipped with Apache POI. I'm suspecting you're running the JAR, instead of running your class (with the JAR on the classpath).

Answer (score 1):

Please run the class file using right click run option. The above message while come when the only JAR file is getting run.