# Trying to print xlsx content with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I want to read a .xlsx file and display the content. For that purpose I added these libraries:

- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
- poi-3.11-20141221.jar
- poi-examples-3.11-20141221.jar
- poi-excelant-3.11-20141221.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.11-20141221.jar

I get this error:

> Usage: BiffDrawingToXml [options] inputWorkbook Options:
>   -exclude-workbook            exclude workbook-level records   -sheet-indexes      output sheets with specified indexes   -sheet-namek          output sheets with specified name

Could anyone tell me what's happening please? Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
/**
* @author giftsam
*/
public class Principal
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {       
        File myFile = new File("C://2feb15.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

        // Finds the workbook instance for XLSX file
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);

        // Return first sheet from the XLSX workbook
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();

        // Traversing over each row of XLSX file
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();             

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");                 
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                default :

                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: first of all i dont think you need these many jar files to read an xml file.... only poi.jar, jxl.jar and jexcel.jar should be enough to do that

Comment: @sumitsabhnani Thanks for the feedback. Anyway, I guess the error doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: Search this site, there are already answers on why it is not working.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703988/the-poireadexcelfile-class-will-read-in-the-poi-test-xls-file-into-an-hssfwork

Comment: how do you start the program? if via command line: what's the command line you're using? It looks like you're starting a whole different program.